# c# wpf ContentControl and multiple UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple "states" where each state is just `UserControl` with different functionality like display video or image and some different stuff, and user is able to create a list of states and change background of main window where `ContentControl` with actual state is placed. It works great but the issue is when user changes `bg` color to lets say white then during transition between states screen goes black for a short time. It's probably because i'm creating new instance of `UserControl` each transition like:

```
contentControl.Content = new StartState();
```

So i thought about making a list of all `UserControl` instances, but the thing is user may create a lot of states and unnecessary take some memory away. Is there any better option to make it no memory dependent and make transition fast (at least without screen changing to black for a moment).

Answer (score 0):

If the `StartState` has configuration related to background color and other visual stuff, I'd make sure the new object was set up correctly before setting the `contentControl.Content`.  Try instantiating and preparing the new `StartState` object before setting `contentControl.Content` to it.

```
var newStartState = new StartState();
newStartState.Background = Colors.White;
newStartState.SomeProperty = Foo;
newStartState.OtherProperty = Bar;
contentControl.Content = newStartState;
```

Comment: I've tried it and result is the same, i think MediaElement causes the black flash but im not sure how to get rid of it

Comment: I think you should update your question with more information then.  A `MediaElement` object is not mentioned, so there's no way to know if it's causing this behavior or not.  Try making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).